# React & dealing with asynchronous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Our React application talks to an API via a library that heavily depends on promises.

We might for example pass an "User resource" around. When we render a User component, this component gets access to the users' properties by calling `await User.get()` in `componentDidMount`.

The implication is that many (if not most) of our components all need to have a `ready` state property, and most of them need to both deal with the case of a first render, and render after the user properties have been received.

This feels clunky. One idea we had was to create components specifically responsible for doing the loading of data, and a second set of "view" components only responsible for rendering after the loading is complete.

One issue here is that the "view" components are often also forms and need to communicate state changes back up the tree.

Not hard to do, but I am mainly curious if there are known good patterns for tackling this sort of thing, or prior art I can base this off. Alternatively, I will also take other suggestions on how to deal with this pattern.

Comment: I feel you're on the right way. There's multiple ways, like an HoC, hooks, a Redux store layer may help decouple this as well (though it is possible without it), a simple fetch component with a render prop used in _container/presentational_ style component architecture. It's really up to you. For data updates up the tree, the container should provide callbacks down to its children so they're completely unaware of the data layer and can focus on UI rendering and behaviours.

Comment: we've written a fetch hoc that we used.  When hooks came out, we wrote a fetch hook.  It handles the async queries, handles rerunning queries when props change.  The component just needs to render appropriately based upon the `result, isLoading, error` values it gets back from the helper.  Search and you'll find such hooks and hocs already out there on npm.  It greatly streamlines the component-writing and eliminates the need for *you* to continually rewrite the same async logic.

Comment: @Brandon do you have an example of a hook/hoc that you like? Not looking for a hard recommendation, I would just like to do some research

Comment: @Evert only opensource HOC I've used is `redux-query` which worked rather well.  I use a proprietary fetch hook these days.  But you can search for react fetch hooks and you will find more than one you can try.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this component with `redux`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Spinner } from "@blueprintjs/core";

export default ({ action, selector, component, errorComponent }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(action());
  }, [dispatch, action]);

  const DispatchFetch = () => {
    const { data, isRequesting, error } = useSelector(selector());
    if (!isRequesting && data) {
      const Comp = component;
      return <Comp data={data}></Comp>;
    } else if (error) {
      if (errorComponent) {
        const ErrorComp = errorComponent;
        return <ErrorComp error={error}></ErrorComp>;
      }
      return <div>{error}</div>;
    }
    return <Spinner></Spinner>;
  };

  return <DispatchFetch></DispatchFetch>;
};
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. The code is a little above my head at the moment, but I'm going to spend some time to figure out if this approach works for me!